# Non-splitting short exact sequence given by nilpotent ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, modules, ideals

I'm trying to solve an exercise (Jon Carlson, Modules and Group Algebras, Exercise 1.1) which says

> If $A$ is a finite dimensional $k$-algebra with $1$ over a field $k$ and $N\subseteq A$ is a non-trivial nilpotent left ideal, then the short exact sequence
> $$0\longrightarrow N\longrightarrow A\longrightarrow A/N\longrightarrow 0$$
> does not split.

Now, if there was an $A$-module morphism right inverse to the projection, let's say $\rho:A/N\longrightarrow A$, it should map a class to one of its elements, namely
$$\rho([a]_N)=a+n_a$$
for some $n_a\in N$. My idea is to consider $a=1\notin N$ and, by nilpotence $N^k=0$, for $k$ minimal, a nonzero product of $k-1$ elements in $N$, call it $m=m_1\cdots m_{k-1}\neq 0$. If we let this $m$ to act, we find

$$m\rho([1]_N)=\rho(m[1]_N)=\rho([m]_N)=\rho(0)=0$$

But therefore we get a contradiction since $$m\rho([1]_N)=m(1+n_1)=m+0\neq 0$$

My concern is about the correctness of this proof, because it seems odd to me that I never used finiteness condition on the dimension of $A$, neither that we are on a field actually. Maybe the result holds for a nil ideal, which is also nilpotent under the assumptions that I didn't touch.

I wonder if someone could tell me if this solution works fine or point me out where anything goes wrong. Thanks in advance!